# Gradle Plugin output name

Tags: gradle, jar

How could I set output name when Gradle builds custom plugin artifact?

I mean when I create a custom plugin and build it Gradle puts `plugin-name-1.0.0.jar` into `build/libs` folder.

By default it gets final `.jar` name from the project folder name.
But I'd like to set it a custom name.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this :

```
jar {
    baseName = 'custom-name'
}
```

You will get `custom-name-1.0.0.jar`

Comment: That's ok. From the [Jar DSL](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.bundling.Jar.html#org.gradle.api.tasks.bundling.Jar:baseName) page I've found `archivesBaseName` property which seems to also set names for Javadoc and sources. Thanks.